# RabbitMQ-Web-Stomp: Recovering connection lost

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

I am using RabbitMQ-web-stomp plugin to connect JS clients to RabbitMQ. As a client I am using SockJS. I can establish the connection successfully and subscribe to exchanges. Once subscribed successfully, messages are received as expected.

But, as I have observed, the connection gets lost frequently and it will stop receiving further messages. To overcome that, I am trying to write some reconnection logic, which will retry connection in `on_error` callback with progressive delay. While doing so, it seems I never get to restore connection with same `connection` object. I need to instantiate the `connection` object subscribe again using:

```
var ws = new SockJS(configurations.webSocket);
var client = Stomp.over(ws);

client.heartbeat.incoming = 0;
client.heartbeat.outgoing = 0;

client.connect('Username', 'Password', function () {
    client.subscribe('/exchange/exchangename/topicname', function (e) {
        //subscription callback
    });
}, function (err) {
            console.log('Error in RabbitMQ connection: ', err);
}, '/');
```

But while doing this, it will create a new queue and all messages published while connection was interrupted will not be delivered to this client.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to specify queue name while subscribing? If so, I can specify old queue name and it may gets bound to existing queue.

I am pretty new to RabbitMQ. So, please suggest if there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve, too.

PS: I am using topic exchanges.

Comment: Did you figured out the way ?

Comment: @slimshadddyyy: unfortunately not yet! 

Comment: Did  you find a way?